# Popup-script in chrome extension sends messages several times

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have my [pop-up script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) for chrome-extension that counts words on the page. So when I click on plugin toolbar icon it starts loading and sends message to the `content-script`, in return that `content-script` replies with word-count info on the page.

```
var Popup = (function () {
    function Popup() {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
            var message = {};
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, message, function (response) {
                alert("!");  // I can see this alert many times (1..4)
                    var count = response.data;
                    if (count != 1) {
                        document.getElementById("word-count").innerText = count;
                    }
            });
        });
    }
    return Popup;
})();
new Popup();
```

The problem is that `sendMessage` is invoking several times (when pop-up script itself load itself only once).

Sometimes it invokes `sendMessage` 1 time, sometimes 2,3,4 but for some pages (like stack-overflow site) only once.

**Q:** I wonder why I could happen?

**UPDATE:**

FYI: I have permission only for one/active tab, here is stuff in my `manifest.json`:

```
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ]
```

Content script section:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "css": ["css/content.css"],
      "all_frames" : true,
      "js": [

        "lib/jquery/jquery.min.js",
        "lib/jquery/jquery.min.map",

        "src/msg/IMessage.js",
        "src/msg/IMessage.ts",


        "src/content/IFrame.js",
        "src/content/IFrame.ts",   
        "src/content/Content.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Does the number of times correlate to the amount of tabs you have open?

Comment: I think it depends but it is not a rule. even when one tab is open I still have that issue.

Comment: By the way, there is no reason to call ``new`` on that function. Similarly, you can get rid of the anonymous function wrapper and that would still be fine.

Comment: that was generated from my TypeScript src file

Comment: Show your content script section from the manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage:

> Sends a single message to the content script(s) in the specified tab, with an optional callback to run when a response is sent back. The runtime.onMessage event is fired in each content script running in the specified tab for the current extension.

This means that if there is a content script running in `<iframe>`s on the tab, those will be executed as well.

Comment: Well, there you have it, Patrick beat me to it. Your content script is injected into all frames. Do note that you can specify the frame ID.

Comment: yes, if look in content script debug info/panel in chrome, it shows that I have 4 content scrips + all what is in lib folder. See seems it is useful bit of doc.

Comment: indeed, my content script Content.js creates IFrame and appends it to to user html page. But I'm listing for the msg only in one place.. and in that place I got message twice and more times. I guess because of that iFrame..so I have to distinguish how to ignore that one that targeting for Ifrmae one.

Answer (score 0):

My problem (also) was in manifest's [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)":

```
"all_frames" : true
```

(now I set it to `false`)

Depending on amount of frames on the pages it kept creating content script instances..